# PyQt5 QTablewidget item alignment

Tags: python, pyqt

what I want is to align my checkbox which is in Qtablewidget.
here is what my script like

```
mylist = [some list I made..]
for i in range(len(mylist)) :
    row_count = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    nowset = row_count+1
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(nowset)
    self.tableWidget.setItem( row_count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(mylist[i]))
    chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()
    chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    self.tableWidget.setItem( i, 1, chkBoxItem)

self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(False)
self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

here is **Question 1. how can I align my QtableWidget item which is chekbox to center.**

from some googling I found that cellwidget does work. so
I tried changing my code to to `cellWidget` not `Item`. 
as like

```
self.checkBoxList= []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    ckbox = QCheckBox()
    self.checkBoxList.append(ckbox)

for i in range(len(mylist)):              
    cellWidget = QWidget()
    layoutCB = QHBoxLayout(cellWidget)
    layoutCB.addWidget(self.checkBoxList[i])
    layoutCB.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)            
    layoutCB.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    cellWidget.setLayout(layoutCB)
    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,1,cellWidget)
```

this those align checkbox as I need. but make other things to problem.

**Question 2. using cellwidget, how can I set all chekbox cellwidget to checked.**

**Qestionn 3. using cellwidget, how can I know which row's are checked.**

**Question 4. using cellwidget, how can I change cell color.**

it seems `item` and `cellwidget` works differently.

because I have button that change all checkbox to checked and

another button that get column 0's text which same row's checkbox is checked.

I also tried delegate like this.

```
class AlignDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
```

and put below code at above `self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(False)`

```
delegate = AlignDelegate(self.tableWidget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
```

don't know why. but doen't work.
**Question 5. why doesn't work?**

here is my screenshot of my program.

[image]

if you can solve Question 1. that would be enough for me.

because other answer will make me to change all following code.

other questions are just telling I tried and they make more problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to center the checkbox then you must use a QProxyStyle:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CheckBoxStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def subElementRect(self, element, option, widget=None):
        r = super().subElementRect(element, option, widget)
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator:
            r.moveCenter(option.rect.center())
        return r


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        for text in data:
            row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)

            text_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text)

            checkbox_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            checkbox_item.setFlags(
                QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
            )
            checkbox_item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, text_item)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, checkbox_item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    checkbox_style = CheckBoxStyle(app.style())
    app.setStyle(checkbox_style)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]